# C# - transform an async task from one type to another

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm used to working with the Scala programming language - using Scala I could map over futures, such as:

```
val response: Future[HttpResponse] = asyncHttpClient.GetRequest("www.google.com")

val statusCode: Future[Int] = response.map(r => r.statusCode)
```

Recently I've picked up working with C#, and I saw myself being in the same situation as the example above, however I couldn't figure out how "map" a task.

Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = httpClient.GetAsync("www.google.com")

Task<int> statusCode = response.Map(response => response.StatusCode)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most direct translation with existing methods would be:

```
Task<int> statusCode = response.ContinueWith(t => t.Result.StatusCode)
```

However in practice you almost always await the task to get the result. Maybe you should look into async/await.

Comment: Essentially Jon Skeet implemented this, however since you actually provide me with a standard library method I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I think @Jon Skeet's answer is also less efficient because it creates the state machine for the await. Not entirely sure though, maybe there is some issue with ContinueWith that I do not see.

Comment: This version will have slightly different exception handling. Yours will raise a `AggrageException` containing the actual exception, John's will raise the actual exception.

Comment: Not only is the exception wrapped, but this method will also run the lambda within the current task scheduler. In this case it *should* work fine, but in the general case `await` is safer than `ContinueWith`.

Comment: Another good point. On the other hand forcing the context may not be desirable for performance reasons. There is a reason people stick ConfigureAwait(false) on their async library calls.

Comment: async-await was the solution for me. Thanks. +1

Comment: I always forget *.Result*  in `x => x.Result`. Tasks in CSharp are so clunky and uggly :/

Answer (score 9):

I'm slightly surprised there isn't anything in the framework for this, to be honest. (More likely, there is an I haven't seen it.) You can build it fairly easily though:

```
public static async Task<TResult> Map<TSource, TResult>
    (Task<TSource> task, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
    => selector(await task.ConfigureAwait(false));
```

Note: using `ConfigureAwait` here isn't always clear-cut. You may want to include a `continueOnCapturedContext` parameter:

```
public static async Task<TResult> Map<TSource, TResult>(
    Task<TSource> task,
    Func<TSource, TResult> selector,
    bool continueOnCapturedContext = false) =>
    selector(await task.ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext));
```

Comment: Maybe because ContinueWith is pretty close?

Comment: There's a whole [LINQ over Tasks](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/04/04/parallelextensionsextras-tour-1-linq-to-tasks/) experiment from TPL extras, but it never really took off.

Comment: @Stilgar: Yes, that's true too.

Comment: @Stilgar today I faced an issue with `ContinueWIth` eating my exceptions since it works for both successful and unsuccessful resolution. Almost two hours spent to find this nuance...

Comment: I suggest adding `ConfigureAwait(false)` since this is library code.

Comment: @DharmaTurtle this is not a clear cut case for using `ConfigureAwait(false)`, because the `await` is followed by invoking a `selector` lambda supplied by the caller. It is possible to be thread-affine code there (accessing UI control properties etc). The best solution is probably the one [chosen by the Polly library](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Asynchronous-action-execution#synchronizationcontext): to  include an optional `bool continueOnCapturedContext = false` argument in the method's signature.

Answer (score 0):

With modern C#, this should be rewritten with `await`:

```cs
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("www.google.com")

var statusCode  = response.StatusCode;
```

This can be used alongside `async` to *create* something that is a `Task<int>`:

```cs
async Task<int> Fetch(string url)
{
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    return response.StatusCode;
}
```

Comment: Since Johan is specifically asking about `how [to] "map" a task`, I believe the other answers are better as they're more "functional programming" style, which he is likely familiar with coming from Scala. Also, `Map` returns a generic so it is much more generalizable.

Comment: @DharmaTurtle this does literally everything that map would do, but in ways that the task API is now optimized for. In terms of returning a generic: the `async` method could itself be generic - again: it is exactly the same, semantically.

Comment: Sadly, I disagree. While I agree that your method accomplishes the same semantic behavior, it fails to generalize to other cases. What if he wants the header instead of the status code? With `Task.Map`, this is easy (`response.Map(r => r.Header`), but with your implementation, he'll need to write a new method. If you feel like diving into FP world, this is a good, though dense post: https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/09/24/asynchronous-functors/ I'm also not sure what you mean by "but in ways that the task API is now optimized for". Skeet's answer also uses `await` - do you take issue with his answer?

Comment: @DharmaTurtle only in so much as: it is *unnecessary* to add a "map" API here; in reality, let's assuming we're using the first version; you literally change `var statusCode = response.StatusCode` to `var header = response.Header` - and you're done. Or more likely, you want to access multiple things from the response, which you've already awaited, so you're just *adding* other things under `var statusCode = response.StatusCode`. Because of this reality (accessing multiple things), the "map" you'd be using would end up being: identity (i.e. `x => x`), which is pointlesss

Comment: "Necessary" is a *very* high bar. E.g. to store data, it isn't necessary to use EF, or SQL, or even a computer. Pen and paper is sufficient. But this doesn't scale, which is my criticism of your solution. Think of all the times you use `Enumerable.Select(x => ...)`. `Task.Map` is ***exactly*** the same, but over the Task functor instead of the List functor. This makes it simple to chain methods when only one is async, in the same way `.Select` allows you to chain methods that only operate on a single list element at a time. Please reexamine the last 3 sentences of my prior comment.